# How can i get the onChange callback from Sorting Component in elastic/react-search-ui?

Tags: reactjs, elasticsearch, swiftype, elastic-search-ui

I need to call one function after the sorting option is clicked. But I can't access the onChange event. The elastic/react-search-ui docs https://docs.elastic.co/search-ui/api/react/components/sorting also didn't provide details about callback for sorting component. please can anyone help with this?